# Equality of complex line integrals along the closed contours $C$ and $C'$ where $C'$ is inside $C$ when we join them with a straight line

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals

In the book of *The theory of Functions* by Titchmarsh, at page 78, after Cauchy's integral theorem, it is given that

> Suppose again that $C$ is a simple closed contour, and $C'$ another
> simple closed contour lying entirely inside $C$. Let $f(z)$ be
> analytic and one-valued at all points in the ring-shaped region
> between $C$ and $C'$. Then $\int_C f(z) = \int_{C'} f(z).$ For we can
> join $C$ to $C'$ by  a straight line $l$ parallel, say, to the real
> axis.Then the region between $C$ and $C'$, cut by $l$, is the inside
> of the contour $\Gamma$, formed by $C$ described positively, $C'$
> negatively, and $l$ described twice in opposite directions.

However, even though, we are traversing on $l$ in opposite directions, the line segments that we are passing on are different. I mean if we traverse $l$ in the positive direction while going from the beginning of $C$ (choose one end as the beginnings) to $C'$, and traversing negatively while going from the end of $C'$ to $C$. Therefore, even even though we pass on $l$ twice, we travel on different parts of $l$, so how can we directly claim that these both integrals, i.e $\int_l f(z)$, cancel each other ?

Edit:

[image]

So, for example, we start from $A$, go along $l$, then traverse $C'$ from $C$ to $D$, and then pass along $l$ again in the same direction, and traverse $C$ from $B$ to $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ be any path. The integral pf $f$ along $\gamma$ is$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^1f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$The opposite path of $\gamma$ is $\gamma^-$ define by $\gamma^-(t)(\gamma(1-t)$.Add\begin{align}\int_{\gamma^-}f(z)\,\mathrm dz&=\int_0^1f\bigl(\gamma^-(t)\bigr){\gamma^-}'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\int_0^1f\bigl(\gamma(1-t)\bigr)\gamma'(1-t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_1^0f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz.\end{align}

Comment: See my edit, you misunderstood me, I think.

Comment: Your drawing has very little to do with the problem that you stated. Only the line segment $[AC]$ (or the line segment $[BD]$) should be there. All the rest of the line sement $[EF]$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Then how can we have a closed contour given that $DB$ is not there ?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was thinking that why do we need them to be closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointing that.

Comment: I did not understand the question clearly, apparently.

Comment: You start from $A$. Then you fallow the path $C$ (by the way, using the same letter for two different things is a **very** bad idea) until you reach $A$ again. Then you go from $A$ to $C$. Then you follow the path $C'$ until you reach the point $C$ once again. Finally, you go back from $C$ to $A$. Is that a closed contour or not?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is. What I was originally thinking was that red lines in the drawing. Thanks a lot again.